# Novel about teleportation and a child assumed to be the savior of the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, novel

I could swear that I got this answered once via the TVTropes YKTS forum, but all I can find is my failed query.

It's a Sci-fi novel, involves the last member of an alien race saying that a particular child will be a savior of the galaxy. Everyone assumes that this means that he will be able to transcend the teleportation limits (if I recall correctly, they could teleport up to some amount, say 22 kilograms, but the moment they added a gram more, it failed). His father was a former football player and it was referenced a few times that he used a football carry for the baby with the head in one hand and the rest of the body on one forearm. The parents were killed by some sort of extremists and the boy was tested for his teleportation abilities and they found that he couldn't transcend the limit. And... that's about all I remember.

I read it in middle school, I believe, so that means it was definitely published before 2000 and likely before 1994.

Comment: The children is supposed to save the galaxy from what?

Comment: @algiogia: 
That I do not remember, unfortunately. I just remember that a big deal was made about him by the alien such that people was following along with what happened to him as he grew up.

Comment: Did they use the word "teleportation" in the book or is a word you use to describe it? Was it a printed book or electronic?

Comment: @algiogia:
Printed book, trade paperback as I remember it. I don't remember the exact word used for the instantaneous transportation, but I want to say that it was long distances, interstellar distances, and there was a strict upper limit on the mass that could be transported.

Comment: Is it "The Journeys of McGill Feighan" of Kevin O'Donnel?

Comment: That's it, @algiogia! Would you like to submit it as an answer so I can give you the bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from Kevin O'Donnell's series "The Journeys of McGill Feighan", probably the first book, "Caverns".

[O'Donnell's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_O'Donnell,_Jr).

> "Caverns" is the first book in a (currently) four book series by Mr. O'Donnell. As the title implies, the focus is on a character named McGill Feighan. In this first book, the origin of McGill and the start of his adventerous life is revealed. "Caverns" is at first a light-hearted read, but you soon find yourself drawn into the life of the hero, his triumphs and despair. McGill is a "flinger", a person who can teleport anything (himself, other people, things) anywhere that he's been before. But even for a flinger, he does not lead a normal life due to unusual events in his life, when he was a newborn. Much of the story revolves around McGill's growing-up and learning to deal with his powers, as well as the assortment of people and aliens that take an interest in his life (both good and bad).

Comment: Thank you. I found a copy and I'm reading through. Man, I messed up some of the details...

Comment: You really made me curious about that book... I'll have to read it.